# Add Tool Tip to File Browse Input

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, microsoft-edge

Given the below code, what's the best way to customize the tool tip for button mouseover? In Chrome the tool tip is auto-set to "No file chosen." In Edge there is no default tool tip. Is JavaScript necessary?

```
<div id="Dialog--Person">
  <form>
    <input placeholder="Enter First Name..." id="personFirstName" >
    <input placeholder="Enter Last Name..." id="personLastName" >
    <input placeholder="Enter Title..." id="personTitle" >
    <input placeholder="Enter Office Phone..." id="personPhone" >
    <input placeholder="Enter Mobile Phone..." id="personMobile" >
    <input placeholder="Enter Email..." id="personEmail" >
    <input type="file" value="upload" class="form-control" id="personPhoto" name="photo">
  </form>
</div>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/dikuw/pen/NYaOpN)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `title` and pass the value whatever you want to display like below concept. it will be work with all browser and show same text in tooltip.

```
<input type="file" value="upload" class="form-control" id="personPhoto" name="photo" title="Please select file.">
```

```html
<div id="Dialog--Person">
  <form>
    <input placeholder="Enter First Name..." id="personFirstName" >
    <input placeholder="Enter Last Name..." id="personLastName" >
    <input placeholder="Enter Title..." id="personTitle" >
    <input placeholder="Enter Office Phone..." id="personPhone" >
    <input placeholder="Enter Mobile Phone..." id="personMobile" >
    <input placeholder="Enter Email..." id="personEmail" >
    <input type="file" value="upload" class="form-control" id="personPhoto" name="photo" title="Please select file.">
  </form>
</div>
```